# why abandoned memory is not taken as leaked memory in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, instruments

Please tell me why abandoned memory is not taken as leaked memory ?

How come the object reference will be there after calling main object's dealloc. ?

According to Instruments,

Leaked Memory is : Allocated memory that no longer can reached.

Abandoned Memory : Accessible allocated memory that is never used.(Wasted or forgotten memory)

Ex : After popOverController is dismissed, all the variables in that viewController is getting released, there are no leaks according to INSTRUMENTS.

But when check through Mark Heap, it is showing me that some memory is getting waste.

Am releasing all variables. 
Once the view dealloc is called, it will release all the correspondent objects,right? 
If it is not able to release, then it will come under Leaks.

Plz help me out, how to catch this abandoned memory? What is the main contributing reason behind this (most common mistake in development)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Leaked memory is very specific - this is allocated memory that you no longer have a reference to in your code.

An app can use "too much" memory (as in, it will receive memory warnings and get shut down by the OS) without leaking a single byte. A huge array of UIImage objects, for example, can take up memory very quickly, but none of it is leaked.

Abandoned memory would fall into this category - if you're taking up space in memory with objects, but never accessing them, this is abandoned memory. Instrument's definition of "never" is of course only as long as you are running the instrument for - you need to access all areas of the functionality of your app.

Now we've cleared up the abandoned / abundant confusion you'll hopefully be able to find other articles and answers, such as the article in comments and [this related, if not duplicate, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011683/tips-for-finding-and-debugging-abandoned-memory-and-heap-growth)

Comment: Hi jruton,

excuse me for my bad english. In have edited my question. Please tell me if you want me to add anything to my question.

Comment: I understand now - I think you've confused the word "abandoned" with the word "abundant" - easy mistake to make for a non-English speaker! There's a good guide to using heap shots in instruments [here](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) which might help.