# Wikitude - Bad memory management / memory leaks

Tags: ios, cordova, memory-leaks, xcode5, wikitude

I'm using wikitude for my augmented reality mobile app project. My problem is I dont know how to manage app memory before and after resume my app. This is my test result on my xcode5. Every time I resume my app during preview world, memory usage keep increasing.

[image: Test result]

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, just update the latest wikitude SDK from github. This happen because of iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

You may have abandoned memory. Take a look at this thread as a good starting point. [Tips for finding and debugging abandoned memory and heap growth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011683/tips-for-finding-and-debugging-abandoned-memory-and-heap-growth)